# bootstrap navbar not showing in desktop email but showing in mobile

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to send html email with bootstrap navbar.
When I view the received mail in my mobile device, I can see the navbar and the html is properly rendered.
But when I view the same received mail in desktop, I cannot see the navbar.  My navbar title is superimposed by my h3 element which is under the navbar.
Is there any configuration that I need to do?

To make it clear, I am seeing it properly using iPhone's email app.  But when I view the yahoo mail in my desktop, it's not showing the navbar bar itself.  The navbar title is written on top of the h3 element that supposed to be below the navbar.

Here's the code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <base href="/"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <span class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h3>Hi,</h3>
            <br>
            <p>Thank you for your email.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The code [looks fine](http://www.bootply.com/1zRJTYMhEQ) so it's probably something to do with how Yahoo mail is rendering the HTML. Perhaps Yahoo is ignoring the `<style></style>` block in the HEAD.

Comment: It's ok, I think i won't use bootstrap css on creating the navbar for my emails.  I just replaced it using <li> items and it works :)